# In a power query, how can I point to the current user directory for the source file?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am going to send this workbook to other users. It will query a file which will be in their user directory.

Excel's power query editor does not accept the %userprofile% I try to put in. It gives me

[image]
How can I make it point towards the current user's directory?

Comment: Where will this workbook be stored? If the workbook itself is not in the current users directory, you may need VBA; if the workbook will be someplace in the current users directory, you can possibly get away with an xlm4 macro (but I think this still requires saving as a xlsm file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a cell formula with whatever you need to get that path.

Give that cell a range name and use it in place of **NamedRangeName** below

replace %USERPROFILE% in your formula with

```
Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NamedRangeName"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Horseyride solutiont is perfect, however I didn't find a function to get enviroment variable directly from the spreadsheet.
I needed a VBA function:

```
Function env(vn As String) As String
   env = Environ(vn)
End Function
```

You can call it from the named cell.